# How can I open a specific Tab View from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, appdelegate, tabbarcontroller

My root view is a tab bar controller, I would like to open the app on a specific tab when a certain notification is received. If I use presentViewController the tab bar disappears. Is there a specific way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let myTabBar = self.window.rootViewController as! UITabBarController // Getting Tab Bar
    myTabBar.selectedIndex = 2 //Selecting tab here
    return true
}
```